# powershell script to kill .exe terminal server disconnected session

Tags: session, powershell, disconnected-session

I'm looking for a method to kill a .exe of disconnected terminal session. It's about Navision; We have limited licences and want to keep killing the ones that aren't in use.

I know there are methods to completely logoff the disconnected session, but I prefer to only close this specific progress.

I did find a blogpost with a code that is discribed to do exactly what i'm looking for. A powershell script that's sheduled to scan for a certain .exe on disconnected sessions, and kill it off. http://www.interworks.com/blogs/jpoehls/2012/12/12/killing-processes-disconnected-terminal-service-sessions the code is posted on this webpage.

Unfortunately it doesn't work, I get the following error:

```
PS C:\scripts> .\navscript.ps1
An empty pipe element is not allowed.
At C:\scripts\navscript.ps1:91 char:10
+         | <<<<  % { $id = $_;
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : EmptyPipeElement
```

Besides alot of time spent on google to find different solutions, I also tried to remove the empty line at line 90. this resulted in another error:

```
PS C:\scripts> .\navscript.ps1
Exception calling "Substring" with "2" argument(s): "Lengte kan niet minder dan nul zijn.
Parameternaam: length"
At C:\scripts\navscript.ps1:52 char:44
+                     ;"ID" = $line.Substring <<<< ($line.IndexOf(" ",     $starters.Username), $starters.ID - $line.IndexO
f(" ", $starters.Username) + 2).trim()
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

I hope someone has an idea how to get this working.

Answer (score 1):

The `query session` command output is localized, therefore its substrings in `Get-Sessions` that are hardcoded into the function are unable to get triggered if the very first line does not match the expected line of:

```
 SESSIONNAME       USERNAME                 ID  STATE   TYPE        DEVICE
```

Note that there's a space at the first symbol of the line.

So, to fix the script, you have to run `query session` on the target PC, get the first line and manually update lines 40 through 45 with correct character sequences displayed in the first line of localized output.